# SQL: speed up searching multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I am a rookie in SQL, so it may be a simple question for someone. Now I have two tables, let's say A and B.

A has columns of "gender", "age", "academic degree", "years of working experience", "state of residence", "skills level", and "career".

B has columns of "gender", "age", "academic degree", "years of working experience", "state of residence", and "annual income". (first 5 are the same as in A)

Now I want to search by these 5 criteria from B and add a column "annual income" to table A. I tried to used INNER JOIN like:

> SELECT A.*, B.annual_income
>
> FROM B INNER JOIN A ON  (A.gender = B.gender)
>
> AND (A.age = B.age)
>
> AND (A.academic_degree = B.academic_degree)
>
> AND (A.years_of_working_experience = B.years_of_working_experience)
>
> AND (A.state_of_residence = B.state_of_residence);

The code did work but it took too long. Does anyone know if there is a much faster algorthm to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query performance tuning can be a tricky topic... I can maybe offer a few tips, though you'll need to consider more information than just what's provided in the question to really nail down a solution.

I gather from your question's tags that you're using MS Access, so that's my working assumption here...  I also assume that the data is local (i.e. stored in the .MDB file, rather than linked remote tables).

The biggest impact you can have on query performance is to make sure your query is cooperating with your physical data model.  The table structure you've described is likely to make life difficult to be honest.

Are there additional columns, like maybe a surrogate key, in each table?  If you can use a simpler join it may help performance.  Whether you have a simpler join key or not, making sure that the join key is properly indexed in both tables is probably the biggest single step that would affect performance.

You ask if there's another algorithm... When writing SQL you don't really think about specific algorithms - the database takes care of that - but to the spirit of the question, I'd say no.  A join is what you need to do.

If this is something you'll need to do multiple times, then it may be worth improving the physical data model.  (If you only need to join the data once, then this may not be worth it because converting the data into the improved model will likely take as long as running the join once.)

So assuming it's the case that each combination of (age,gender,degree,years,state) appears only once in each table, you could create a new table that assigns a unique integer to each combination; then add an indexed integer column to each table to store the assigned value.  A join on that should run better than what you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very helpful reply! I wonder if there is a way to index each person by some numbers: for example, if we have 8 ages, 2 genders, 3 degrees, 6 different numbers of years, and 5 states, can I assign a person who is 6th age, 2nd gender, 1st degree, 5th experience years, and 5th state to an index "62155"?

Comment: What you're describing is more or less a form of "smart key", which tends to be the worst of both worlds between natural keys and surrogate keys; so I wouldn't suggest it.  If you want to assign integers to each combination of attributes, I'd just do it sequentially (and then make sure it's consistent between the two tables).

Comment: I also thought about making it sequentially, but the problem is how to make consistency between two tables. Could you please show me some examples to do such a thing?

Comment: If you KNOW that exactly the same set of (age,gender,degree,years,state) values exist in both tables, then sort the rows in a repeatable way and number sequentially.  Then index the sequential values and the join will be easy.  OR...

Comment: ...if there's a risk that the aren't the same, or if the above is unsuitable for some reason, assign values in one table then join the two on the 5 attributes to copy the values into the 2nd table.  (That's why the fix could take as long as a join, and is then only worth it if you will do the join many times.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct for the task you want to solve, but if you are experiencing performance issues you might have to add indices for your tables. This article is a good place to start learning about that: [Create and use an index to improve performance](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce) (while it's written for Access 2007 it should apply to later versions as well).

On a side note: you're joining the tables on a lot of different columns and the two tables seem to overlap a lot in what they store, which might indicate a problem with the design.

I would think about whether `annual_income` really belongs in a separate table at all - it seem to be dependent on the same key(s) as all the other information. Both tables seem to hold data relating to a single person - is that person an entity in another table, and if so, maybe these two tables should reference that one via a foreign key relationship ?

Your question might be missing some important details about your setup needed to give you a "proper" answer.

Answer (score 0):

never store a data twice.. try to merge the information and get rid of one table. Regarding your question, you can create new column computing hash of all 5 column, and join that column to make it faster.

check this for computing hashes:
https://superuser.com/questions/550592/is-there-an-excel-function-to-create-a-hash-value

Comment: yes...actually I don't know who made these two tables. I will put them together if I am asked to do such thing again next time